# String interning in dictionary keys

Tags: python, python-3.x

Does string interning work on dict keys in python ?
Suppose I have a dictionary of dictionaries and each of the dictionaries in the dictionary has the same keys.

e.g:

dict1 -> keys 'a','b','c'
dict2 -> keys 'a','b','c'

Are the keys for those dictionaries referenced in the same memory place? or the string interning does not come implicitly for those strings ?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What is *string interning*? I am unable to find something like in python docs

Comment: at least i can answer this : Are the keys for those dictionaries referenced in the same memory place? 
unless you did dict1 = dict2, they are not referencing the same memory

Comment: at least i can answer this : Are the keys for those dictionaries referenced in the same memory place? 
unless you did dict1 = dict2, they are not referencing the same memory

Comment: @MEdwin I'm trying to reduce the memory consumption for a data structure like this and I would like to know if there is any way to have the same memory space for the keys of a dictionary, the values in the dictionaries are different. I know that the interning mechanism is done automatically in strings Python but I'm not sure about the string keys of dictionaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, strings and integers are interned, but only small strings and integers.

```
>>> list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'longer and more complicated string']
>>> list2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'longer and more complicated string']
>>> list1[0] is list2[0]
True
>>> list1[1] is list2[1]
True
>>> list1[2] is list2[2]
True
>>> list1[3] is list2[3]
False
```

Two dicts with the same keys are allowed to have completely different values, however - the key-value mapping is tied to the dict's instance (and also to the hashes of the keys, moreso than the keys themselves), not to the key's instance, and dicts are *not* interned at all.

```
>>> dict1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
>>> dict2 = {'a': 3, 'b': 4}
>>> for (key1, key2) in zip(dict1.keys(), dict2.keys()):
...     print(key1 is key2, end="; ")
...     print(dict1[key1] is dict2[key2])
... 
True; False
True; False
```

If you wish to save memory by having only one key-value mapping, have you considered making the dictionary values be tuples? e.g.

```
# instead of
dict1[key] -> value1
dict2[key] -> value2

# do
dictx[key] -> (value1, value2)
```

Comment: Yes, I was not asking if the dicts are interned, only the strings from the dict keys. This answers my question thank you.

Comment: This won't be the whole story; strings literals in a function will be interned in the function's `co_consts` attribute (in CPython), so a function which creates dictionaries with string literal keys should produce dictionaries sharing the same string objects as keys, for example.